# Elements not sitting side by side (Complex Grid) There is space, but acts as if there isn't

Tags: html, css, layout, susy

Having problems executing a complex layout with minimal usage of relative and absolute positioning.

### Here's my layout:

[image]

All my elements are floating left sitting side by side with only a single problem: the border img needs to bleed down into the next row. How can I do that while preventing the elements in the 2nd row (the `CTA` elements) from scooting down below the lower margin of `border img?`

#### This is what happens if I set the height of `border img`

[image]

#### For clarification:

The dom is such that `border img` is between `main_sidebar` and `CTA_top_container.`

1. main_side_image
2. main_heading_container
3. main_sidebar
4. border_img
5. CTA_top_container
6. CTA_Button_relative

#### Closing thoughts:

I have some ideas, like floating right the border img as a div (or susy's `last`) and setting `background-image` as 60% width and positioned on the left of the div or nesting an absolute positioned img inside of a relative container to nudge it over to the left, but i am afraid of destroying the fluidity of the layout (it's inside of a susy fluid grid).

Any thoughts?

Comment: First thought is Wow! Put a JsFiddle on that bad boy, because its fairly complicated to decipher.

Comment: I would love to, but I am not exactly sure how to add external resources. I'm using normalize, sass, and susy. Do you know where I can find their resource links?

Comment: Here's them mockup I did through wix. Dunno if that helps you visualize it.
http://andrewmcswain.wix.com/intensivaotosite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you float the `border_img` right instead of left (with some right margin to push it off the edge), everything else should be able to flow around it.

You might also want to use a grid with more columns. If you're always having to split columns into fractions, it's not really the right grid for the job.

Comment: Thanks again, Eric. I agree about my grid. I'm aware that I'm not using the framework properly. Fixing the grid is on the checklist!